# Where is the information located in Magento on a sales order for discount information on the API

Tags: api, magento

I just want to start out this post by saying that I am not a programmer, nor do I play one on TV.  I have found this site because I have been trying to manage our Magento instance, after pretty much left high and dry by the developers we had building this for us.  I will try and explain it the best I can below:

When we apply a shopping cart coupon to the sales order, and the discount is applied to each item, a new line item total is configured by Magento.  We then have a connector that takes the information from Magento's API and it is then connected to Open Bravo, which is our ERP accounting software.  Open Bravo is grabbing the information as it normally does, however it doesn't see the discount information, so the order total is different in our accounting program then what Magento has.  Open Bravo is teling me they need to know where the discounted amount on the sales order in Magento is on the API.  It's obviously in a different spot then the standard sales order amount.

I might be able to describe a little better if you hit me with questions.  Any help you could provide would be highly appreciated.  Maybe we could barter for some office supplies, as that is what we sell.

Thanks!

Comment: This may be better off on http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Magento API to fetch order information from magento, then below link will be helpful to find actual value.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html

It seems that your ERP is storing "base_grand_total" value in stead of "grand_total".

Comment: I am so blown away be this that I can't even tell you!  Thank you so much for taking the moment to provide an answer.  I will update if I can make this work.

Comment: Our ERP also grabs the line item price, and line item total.  It appears that Magento applies the discount at the line item level first.  So is this where on the API we would grab the information: string 
"discount_percent"
"Discount percent"
string 
"discount_amount "
Discount amount
string 
"base_discount_amount "
Base discount amount